# Intermittent NATS Connection failures with timeouts on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, clojure, nats.io

We have a clojure application that users NATS and the NATS Java libraries to support clustering. This is all deployed on AWS EC2 instances.

Starting last night we are seeing intermittent connection timeouts between the application and the NATS instance. We didn't change any code and don't know of any network or AWS configuration changes. The errors started occurring in all environments at the same time.

Our connection code:

```
defn connect
  "Create a Nats connect and return a Connection object.
     @urls -> Nats server urls (\"nats://127.0.0.1:4222\"), either a seq or comma separated string
     returns <- a Nats Connection object"
  ([]
   (connect ["nats://127.0.0.1:4222"]))
  ([urls]
   (->> (.. (Options$Builder.)
            (errorListener (make-error-handler))
            (connectionListener (make-connection-handler))
            (servers (into-array String urls))
            (executor pool)
            build)
        (Nats/connect))))
```

We also modified the connection code above to update the timeout to be 10 seconds and still are seeing timeouts with an error like the one below.

```
NATS Error Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to NATS servers: nats://my.nats.uri:4222.
    at io.nats.client.impl.NatsConnection.connect(NatsConnection.java:235)
    at io.nats.client.impl.NatsImpl.createConnection(NatsImpl.java:29)
    at io.nats.client.Nats.createConnection(Nats.java:247)
    at io.nats.client.Nats.connect(Nats.java:164)
...
```

Without a code change what could cause NATS connections to start failing in that fashion?

Comment: Hi! Which version of the NATS Server and client library are you using? Do you see any errors in the nats-server logs?

Comment: This ended up being a very strange error in the AWS NLB. There were no errors on the NATS logs.